# Angular 11 run on SSR @nguniversal/express-engine ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

Trying to run `@angular/fire` on Angular 11 and `@nguniversal/express-engine` (SSR).
When init `AngularFireModule` in `app.module.ts` there are error when running command `npm run dev:ssr` or `npm run serve:ssr` it is ok when `ng serve`. Same problem with angular 10 version. Does any one have any clue what to do ?

**app.module.ts:**

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    AppRoutingModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    // AngularFirestoreModule,
    // AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence({ synchronizeTabs: true }),
    // AngularFireFunctionsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In server/main.js file **Error:**

```
globalThis.ɵAngularfireInstanceCache || (globalThis.ɵAngularfireInstanceCache = new Map());
^

ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined
    at Module.<anonymous> (D:\projects\assistant-art.com\dist\Assistant-Art\server\main.js:128059:1)
    at Module.spgP (D:\projects\assistant-art.com\dist\Assistant-Art\server\main.js:128165:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\projects\assistant-art.com\dist\Assistant-Art\server\main.js:26:30)
    at Module.k6Fv (D:\projects\assistant-art.com\dist\Assistant-Art\server\main.js:115283:71)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\projects\assistant-art.com\dist\Assistant-Art\server\main.js:26:30)
    at Module.ZAI4 (D:\projects\assistant-art.com\dist\Assistant-Art\server\main.js:67605:81)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\projects\assistant-art.com\dist\Assistant-Art\server\main.js:26:30)
    at Module.24aS (D:\projects\assistant-art.com\dist\Assistant-Art\server\main.js:38291:69)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\projects\assistant-art.com\dist\Assistant-Art\server\main.js:26:30)
    at Module.K011 (D:\projects\assistant-art.com\dist\Assistant-Art\server\main
.js:52876:80)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was just facing a similar issue while trying to prerender my Angular 11 App using Firebase Database.

**The solution**

The solution that worked for me, was to upgrade node to a version that supports the globalThis (v12 or above [release note](https://twitter.com/mathias/status/1120700101637353473)). So if that is okay with you, the fix could simply be to do something like this:

```
# Install and use node version 12+ 
nvm install 14
nvm use 14
# Persist the node version
nvm alias default 14
```

**Explanation**

The globalThis object was introduced in ES10 (ES2019) to create a uniform way of accessing global variables in all js environments substituting 'window', 'self' or 'frames' (read more here https://www.w3schools.io/javascript/es10-globalthis/).

In the latest release of @angular/fire (v6.1.1) which was release 2 days ago, the globalThis object is now used to access a cached instance of its dependency modules (in this [commit](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/commit/b666a80f7917c55e4beda20afacdcb279eb78e9a)). Previous version of Angularfire did not reference this object, so if it's not possible for you to upgrade the node version you might also resolve the issue by downgrading to the previous version of Angularfire:

`npm i @angular/fire@6.0.5`

However, the previous version has some other issue that also might impact your project so it's probably a no go. The SSR server seems to hang for some time when querying the database due to Angularfire zone integration, as described here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2420.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Found the different solution to. I'll check your one and see are it working to. XD I'm already using node v12 think so.

Comment: Your solution works and it's better. XD Thanks for helping.

Comment: I am trying to use firebase hosting for deploying angular 11 app. I am already on NodeJS 12+ and even npm run serve:ssr works fine. Issue happens when I deploy to firebase hosting which still uses NodeJS 10 runtime. It goves globalThis error.

Comment: It makes sense that you get this error if you are still running NodeJS 10 on your Firebase host. You can upgrade to node 12 instead by changing the version in functions/package.json - it should be as simple as changing the engines entry to: "engines" : { "node" : "12"}. Haven't tried it myself yet, but the procedure is described in the Firebase manual here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_runtime_options