# Can't update firebase function to node 12 in Angular Universal app with AngularFire

Tags: node.js, firebase, angularfire, angular-universal

I followed this tutorial to deploy Angular Universal to a firebase function and deploy with Firebase: https://medium.com/@chris.duebbert/angular-9-universal-firebase-deploy-8d8d47244e1c

Everything worked fine until I add AngularFireModule to my app.module.ts. Then when I run 'ng deploy' using node 12 I get the following error in the logs of my 'ssr' function:

Provided module can't be loaded.
Is there a syntax error in your code?
Detailed stack trace: ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined

When I try with my local node version set to 10 I get the same error directly in my terminal.

Apparently, Firebase uses globalThis which requires node version 12 ([Angular 11 run on SSR @nguniversal/express-engine ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64917442/angular-11-run-on-ssr-nguniversal-express-engine-referenceerror-globalthis-is)). I added the following to my /functions/package.json:

app.module.ts

```
    "engines": {
        "node": "12"
      },
```

I can put any number for node version and my SSR function is still deploying with node 10 and the 'globalThis' error continues. I'm using Firebase's Blaze plan. Here's my app.module.ts:

```
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
        AppRoutingModule,
        NoopAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        NgxTwitterTimelineModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(config),
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

functions/package.json

```
    {
      "name": "functions",
      "scripts": {
        "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
        "build": "tsc",
        "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
        "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
        "start": "npm run shell",
        "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
        "logs": "firebase functions:log"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": "12"
      },
      "main": "lib/index.js",
      "dependencies": {
        "firebase-admin": "^9.4.2",
        "firebase-functions": "^3.13.0",
        "grpc": "^1.24.4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "tslint": "^5.12.0",
        "typescript": "^3.8.0",
        "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
      },
      "private": true
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to polyfill globalThis https://github.com/angular/angularfire#polyfills

Comment: I tried importing the 'globalthis' package and adding import 'globalthis/polyfill'; and import 'globalthis; to my polyfill.ts file but got the same error. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Try polyfilling in your server.ts for SSR.

Comment: You need `import 'globalthis/auto';`.

Comment: Adding import 'globalthis/auto'; at the top of server.ts worked. Thanks!

Comment: import 'globalthis/auto'; at the top of server.ts also worked for me. Thanks a lot. It even works for deploying angular SSR project as a firebase cloud function.

Comment: For the other angular users, you can use  `npm i globalthis` and then add `import 'globalthis/auto';` to the bottom of src/polyfill.ts file.

Answer (score 4):

Two weeks looking for a solution, until I have found this question/answer. Thank you!

Steps to solve the problem:

```
> npm install globalthis
```

on `server.ts` file:

```
import 'globalthis/auto';
```